# Retrieve X-Request-Id from response header in React App

Tags: reactjs, https, header

I have a React app where I am using the `https` module to make a call to an API. I need to be able to retrieve the x-request-id from the response header, however, the response header is only returning the `content-type`. How would I be able to get `x-request-id` to show up in the response header?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
import https from 'https';

getData(bodyData) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const postData = JSON.stringify(bodyData);
        const request = https.request({
            hostname: 'https/myhostname',
            path: '/my/path',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'x-api-key': 'MY_ID', 
                authorization: 'MY_TOKEN',
                'x-product': 'MY_PRODUCT_ID',
                'x-product-location': 'MY_LOCATION',
            },
            withCredentials: false,
            dataType:'json',
            processData: false,

        }, (res) => {
            // need to get x-request-id from response header here
            const req = request;
            if (res.statusCode >= 300) {
                const myError = new Error(res.statusCode);
                resolve(myError);
            }
            else {
                let data = '';
                res.on('data', chunk => data += chunk);
                res.on('end', () => {
                    // Success!
                    try {
                        resolve(JSON.parse(data));
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        resolve(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        request.write(postData);
        request.end();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this a CORS request? Btw, who sends the response is the server. Does it send `x-requrest-id`?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm not sure about React App, generally you have to add `X-REQUEST-D` in header of response. For example in flask I do the following.

```
from flask_log_request_id import current_request_id
            headers = {
               'X-REQUEST-ID' : current_request_id()
            }
```

As code states, current_request_id() returns the current X-REQUEST-ID which can be passed on to the respone header.

> How would I be able to get x-request-id to show up in the response
>   header?

You should search module similar to current_request_id() in REACT which can return you the current X-REQUEST-ID and you can append it to the header.

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing you have to send `x-request-id` as response header from express server.
This library generates UUID for request and add it to X-Request-Id header. In case request contains X-Request-Id header, uses its value instead.

You could use npm module `express-request-id` for this use case.

```
var app = require('express')();
var addRequestId = require('express-request-id')();

app.use(addRequestId);

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send(req.id);
    next();
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

Hope that helps!!!